# Find iPhone using Apple Watch

Tags: iphone, icloud, bluetooth, apple-watch, find-my-iphone

I’m imagining a scenario in which I lose my iPhone. There's nobody about so I cannot go to Find My on iCloud. But I still have my Apple Watch on my wrist.

Can my Apple Watch do one or both of these:

1. Ping when it loses Bluetooth range with my iPhone (therefore, it pings when I lose my iPhone).
2. Show me the last known location of my iPhone.